# What is the plot behind the end of 'Fifty Shades of Grey'?

Tags: plot-explanation, fifty-shades-of-grey

Just watched Fifty Shades of Grey,

I really could not understand what the ending plot of the movie is. What does it conclude as? I don't expect a clear ending but there would be something which clears the moviegoer's mind with such type of ending, which I did not feel. What character does Christian Grey have? What is the reason behind his unacceptable touch?

Comment: Related: [Why doesn't Grey allow Anastasia to touch him?](http://movies.stackexchange.com/q/31659/49)

Comment: It does not answer all queries that are in my question

Comment: I didn't say it does. But I also have a hard time gathering all the queries you're making in this question. What do you mean by "the ending plot" and "what character Christian grey has"? This sounds quite  bit broad and you might want to elaborate what specific parts were unclear to you in order flesh out the question a little more.

Comment: @NapoleonWilson it s clear in my question. character of christian grey was because of his mom or something else.it s confusing and why such type of movie ends with pathetic plot

Comment: As said, feel free to [edit] any clarifications into the question. "What is the ending plot of the movie?" is *not* particularly clear, unless you haven't seen the film.

Comment: @Imran if it was clear in your question, we wouldn't be telling you it was unclear

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The movie ended as the book did. The reason Christian acts like he does (his characterization) is because he is a child victim of sexual abuse and rape by an aunt or friend of the family. That woman used BDSM on him like he wants to use on Anna. That's also the same reason he does not want to sleep with Anna in the same bed.

The real reason the movie and the book ended that way is for the sequel to begin and explain more. It was never intended to be a stand alone movie.

Comment: it s clear as i haven't read the book. i will go with the book